# How to load data dynamically into highcharts charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

This is the chart I want to use for my project, [Column Drilldown](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown)
, and I use node.js to send data from a database to the client side but I don't know how to feed the data which come from the server into the chart data.
This is the data which I get from the server and want to feed it into the chart

```
$.get('Index_api/SoldProductsByName', updateView)

     var ProductByName = {};
 function updateView(data){
    var i=0;
     $.each(data, function(key, item)
     {
           ProductByName= {'name': item.Product_Name, 'y':item.TOTALSOLD,'drilldown':item.Product_Name};



    });


 }
```

I have tried to place the ProductByName into `data` object of the `Highchart` but did not work

Comment: Paste the sample of your data returned from the request.

Comment: @morganfree
I didn't get what do you mean by the sample of your data returned from the request.
Which request exactly you mean.

Comment: @a.Sahel what does your drilldown data look like? Your code has data for the main series `{name, y}` but there isn't any data for the drilldown series. do you have this available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted appears incomplete. It looks like you are iteratively overwriting `ProductByName` w/ a new object; what you need is an array of objects for your series data. If you have drilldown data, that will need to be its own set of data keyed off of `item.Product_Name`.

Below I have altered your `udpateView` method to load your base series data, however, it doesn't look like you have any drilldown data.

```
$.get('Index_api/SoldProductsByName', updateView);

function updateView(data) {
    var i = 0, series = [], drilldown = [];
    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
        series.push({
            name: item.Product_Name
            , y: item.TOTALSOLD
            , drilldown: item.Product_Name
        });
    });

    Highcharts.chart('your-chart-container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: { 
            type: 'category'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Product',
            data: series
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: drilldown
        }
    });
}
```